# Deleting custom object via destructiveChanges.xml and Metadata API deploy()

Tags: metadata-api, workbench, destructivechanges.xml

I've created a custom object in a developer edition org with the sole intention of deleting it via the Metadata API as per [Deleting Components from an Organization](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_deploy_deleting_files.htm).

[image: Custom Object To Be Deleted]

To do this I created the following files:

**package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <version>33.0</version>
</Package>
```

**destructiveChanges.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>DFB__ObjectToBeDeleted__c</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
</Package>
```

Then zipped them both into destructiveChanges.zip.
[image: Destructive Changes Zip]

I uploaded the resulting zip file to the [Workbench Metadata Deploy](https://workbench.developerforce.com/metadataDeploy.php) page and deployed it.

The processing status came back as successful.

[image: Workbench Metadata deploy result]

However, the custom object is still present and there is no indication that it has been deleted.

I've tried:

- both with and without the namespace prefix for the member name in the destructiveChanges.xml.
- change the package manifest version to be 32.0 to match the version that Workbench is using.
- checking Purge On Delete in the Workbench deploy options.
- both including and excluding the `version` element in the destructiveChanges.xml.

**Why can't I delete this custom object using destructive changes?**

Note that this will ultimately be part of a much larger set of deletions. I could potentially use [deleteMetadata()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_deleteMetadata.htm), but I'd rather figure out what is wrong with my [deploy()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_deploy.htm) call.

Comment: Looks good, must be something really trivial! Is it possible the script is using username and password for different org? Or maybe there is a switcheroo between destructiveChanges.xml and package.xml?

Comment: @bigassforce Yes, I think I've got tripped up on something stupid. I've started doing things like checking the double quotes are correctly encoded in the XML.

Comment: Do you get the same result with the actual ant force.com migration tool?

Comment: I don't know, I'll try. I've mostly just used the APIs directly, which is why I was using Workbench to rule out anything I've done.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It turns out the following [DeployOptions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_deploy.htm#deploy_options) setting was what I was missing:

> **singlePackage**
>   *boolean*
>   Indicates whether the specified .zip file points to a directory structure with a single package (true) or a set of packages (false).

I needed to set this to true, as I assume my flat zip file represents a single package. After doing that the *Number of Components Deployed* became 1 and the custom object moved into Deleted Objects (as I hadn't checked purgeOnDelete).

Comment: Your description of process and your self-posted solution were very helpful for guiding me through my first destructiveChanges.xml deployment. Thank you for your thoroughness!